# Facebook delegates are not calling after authentication: cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocos2d-iphone

He guys, I am doing a photo share in my `cocos2d` application with `Facebook SDK`. I've a problem that: the login view with status `Not Logged In` is remaining even `after authentication`. I'm attaching the images: 
[image]

**Problem:** After clicking the `Skip` or `OK` button of the `Authentication page`, the status has to be changed as `Login`. But it isn't. No Facebook delegates are getting called after Auth(When I enter the page first time, `loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser` delegate was get called. After auth, nothing is get called.).

**What I've done already:**

- Downloaded the Facebook SDK, attached to the project.
- Added `FacebookAppID`,`FacebookDisplayName` and `URL Schemes` in `info.plist`.
- Tried the integration with my `cocos2d` app.
- Added `<FBLoginViewDelegate>` in `.h`.
- Added `loginview.delegate = self` in `.m`.

I'm also uploading the screenshot of what I've done in my `info.plist`:
[image]

I am creating the login view as:

```
// Create Login View so that the app will be granted "status_update" permission.
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];

loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
#ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_7_0
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
        loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 25);
    }
#endif
#endif
#endif
loginview.delegate = self;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:loginview];
[loginview sizeToFit];
```

**What I found:**
The following method in `appdelegate` is not get called:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                    fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                        NSLog(@"In fallback handler");
                    }];
}
```

**Further info:**

- Xcode Version 5.0.1
- iOS Version 7.0
- facebook-ios-sdk-3.9

Any help ASAP is appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: so basically after clicking on ok on facebook you app is called back?

Comment: While clicking on 'OK' or 'Skip', it returns to the 'Login Page'. But no delegates gets called...

Comment: could you post the method (code) you use for the authorization?

Comment: I've updated my post (I'm using facebook-ios-sdk-3.9).

Comment: @elio.d: thank you very much for the support. I've solve it. It was my own mistake... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry guys.... `@elio.d`: and thank you very much for your valuable suggestion . That was my mistake with coding. I have pasted the following method, just above `@implementation AppController`. What an idiot I am. This just wasted one of my whole day... :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
}
```

This just saved me. Hope this might be helpful for some others like me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an url scheme in your app to make the facebook app / website call your app back after login or authorization [link to the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/), this is the reason why your app is not called

Comment: You mean: create an array key called URL types with a single array sub-item called URL Schemes. Give this a single item with your app ID prefixed with fb, right? I've already mentioned it in the question that i've added that in info.plist. If that is not what you are mentioning, then pls,pls help...

Comment: Oh sorry I did not see it in the question